# React Native: Animated sliding transition for Views

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

What is the idiomatic way to implement sliding View transitions in React Native? My Layout looks like this:

[image]

I want to transition from View 1 to View 2 with the following behaviour:

[image]

View 1 moves to the left slowly as View 2 replaces it.

I have modelled state in my react native app with Redux and the View change toggles are triggered by Redux events.

Answer (score 0):

try to panResponder :) PanResponder lifecyle solve your problem :)
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html